# Раскрывающийся блок

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на надпись "Показать текст полностью" блок с текстом должен раскрываться, при повторном нажатии закрываться.
Я написал скрипт, но он работает один раз. То есть блок раскрывается, я нажимаю повторно, блок закрывается и всё, дальше он перестаёт открывать/закрывать.
В чём проблема? http://jsfiddle.net/50gsLtL2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас скрипт в принципе работает неправильно, вот что происходит в скрипте:

1. Первый клик: условие сравнения ("" < 160), выдаёт true, поэтому блок раскрывается.
2. Второй клик: условие сравнения ("160px" < 160), выдаёт false, поэтому блок закрывается.
3. Третий клик и последующие: условие сравнения ("50px" < 160), выдаёт false, поэтому блок остаётся закрытым.

Чтобы скрипт заработал как надо, нужно немного его дописать:

```
document.getElementById('text').style.height = "50px"; // Чтобы скрипт видел высоту блока при первом нажатии

if (parseFloat(document.getElementById('text').style.height)<160) // Нужно приводить получаемую высоту к числу, чтобы было правильное сравнение
```

[Пример того](http://jsfiddle.net/50gsLtL2/9/), что получается в итоге и работает как надо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё понятно объяснили! Только обязательно в JS коде указывать высоту блока 50px, в CSS же это прописано?

Comment: @Евгений_21, [вот тут][1] очень хорошо, объясняют почему так происходит


  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes#getcomputedstyle-%D0%B8-currentstyle

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте

```
<script>
function look(type){
param=document.getElementById(type);
if(param.style.display == "none") param.style.display = "block";
else param.style.display = "none"
}
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="look('div1'); return false;">показать/скрыть</a>
Тест
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Больше текста
</div>
```